# Something like \setkomafont{item}{\sffamily}

Tags: enumerate, koma-script, itemize, enumitem

Just to confirm I didn’t overlook something: It’s possible in KOMA-Script to change the font of the `item` label in `description` lists, but neither the label of `enumerate` and `itemize` items nor the `item` font itself. Is that correct? Is there an elegant way to extend `\setkomafont`, `\addtokomafont` and `\usekomafont`?

```
\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\scshape}
```

JFTR, the `enumitem` seems to be limited in the same way.

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item How to change the font that is used here?
\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item … or here
\end{enumerate}
\begin{description}
  \item[descriptionlabel] … or here
\end{description}
```

Comment: `enumitem` is limited in the same way? In what sense? If I remember correctly `\setlist[enumerate]{font=\sffamily}` sets the *enumerate* label in `\sffamily`.

Comment: Okay, that should have been “in a similar way”, since it also doesn’t change the item font.

Comment: Sorry, I think the question is not clear. I just read again and I did not understood. What is the real question? Could you add more details or rephrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>*Small note*: a compilable example is always preferred rather than just a snippet of code.</sub>

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\usekomafont{enumerate}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\usekomafont{itemize}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{description}{\usekomafont{description}}
\newkomafont{description}{\scshape}
\newkomafont{enumerate}{\itshape}
\newkomafont{itemize}{\slshape}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item How to change the font that is used here?
\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item … or here
\end{enumerate}
\begin{description}
  \item[descriptionlabel] … or here
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]